# Java- Getting variables from method into other method

Tags: java, variables, methods

I am struggling with getting variables (all kinds: arrays, Strings, int) from a method (the method where I create the my GUI fields) into another method (the method where i manage my keypress events) I managed to get the fields, via their names, but I don't know how to get some variables.

Example: In the Field Method i got this part:
I manage My timestuff and put it into the input field(s) (rest is cut out)

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.clear(Calendar.HOUR); today.clear(Calendar.MINUTE); today.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
Date todayDate = today.getTime();
long todayDateUnix = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();;
String reportDate = df.format(todayDate);   
String CustomDate = "meinDatum";
String[] parts = reportDate.split("/");
String DateDay = parts[0];
String DateMonth = parts[1];
String DateYear = parts[2];


JTextField input_day =new JTextField(DateDay);
//  input_day.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);  
input_day.setName("input_day");
input_day.setBounds(102, 37, 25, 20);
input_day.setColumns(10);
```

and in the other method I need these variables:

```
input_datum.setText(reportDate);
if(check_datum.isSelected()){
    CustomDateFinal[0] = datumvar;
    input_datum.setText(CustomDateFinal[0]);

}
```

Don't care for the others but how for example do I get "reportDate"?
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
I want the variables from "createFields" to "customKeyevent"
[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmSUt.jpg)

Comment: You can't. Find another way.

Comment: are these methods part of the same class ?

Comment: They are in the same class yes

Comment: You can declare the fields at class-level, then one methods *sets* the values and an other *reads* them. Make sure you don't try to read them before they are set though.

Comment: aka global variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a design problem:
The objet containing the methods `createFields` and `customKeyEvent` has to exchange some values between those.

Then, you could create a structure (class) return by `createFields`, that contains your created field and the values `customKeyEvent` needs.
Or, you could externalize values and create type's properties. During the call of `createFields`, set the properties value, and after, you could get it from customKeyEvent. But take care of possibly multithreading access: choose the good accessibility of your properties for your problem.

I think the second choice is the best ; these solution respect the role suggested by the name of `createFields` method.

It could be a good practice to you to learn about [design patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns). That's some classics of basic design problem resolution.

It still helps me every day.

Answer (score 1):

Are these methods in the same class? If so, why don't you declare the variables outside the method? That way their scope is across all methods. If not, you could create getters/setters for each variable.